# Can't install ROS2 Humble on RasPi with Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a fresh Ubuntu Server 22.04 64Bit installation on my Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB and followed the instructions exactly, here's my history:

```
    1  sudo apt update
    2  sudo apt upgrade
    3  uname -a
    4  sudo reboot now
    5  uname -a
    6  sudo apt update
    7  sudo apt upgrade
    8  locale
    9  sudo apt update && sudo apt install locales
   10  sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
   11  sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   12  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   13  locale
   14  apt-cache policy | grep universe
   15  sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl gnupg lsb-release
   16  sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
   17  echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(source /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
   18  sudo apt update
   19  sudo apt upgrade
   20  sudo apt install ros-humble-ros-base
```

This returns the following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install ros-humble-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv but it is not going to be installed
 libprocps8 : Depends: libsystemd0 (>= 209) but it is not installable
 util-linux : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

The fun part is that all dependencies are already installed, they're just not found:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install libapt-pkg6.0 libsystemd0 systemd-sysv libudev1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libapt-pkg6.0 is already the newest version (2.4.5).
libsystemd0 is already the newest version (249.11-0ubuntu3).
libudev1 is already the newest version (249.11-0ubuntu3).
systemd-sysv is already the newest version (249.11-0ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep libapt-pkg6.0
ii  libapt-pkg6.0:arm64             2.4.5                                   arm64        package management runtime library
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep libsystemd0
ii  libsystemd0:arm64               249.11-0ubuntu3                         arm64        systemd utility library
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep libudev1
ii  libudev1:arm64                  249.11-0ubuntu3                         arm64        libudev shared library
```

Just for the sake of completeness:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-1011-raspi #13-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 2 11:44:34 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

So how can I get ROS2 on my RasPi?

Edit: other packages can be installed without any problems:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  net-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 207 kB of archives.
After this operation, 774 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 net-tools arm64 1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5 [207 kB]
Fetched 207 kB in 0s (831 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package net-tools.
(Reading database ... 100554 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../net-tools_1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking net-tools (1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5) ...
Setting up net-tools (1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                                                      
Scanning processor microcode...                                                                                                                                                            
Scanning linux images...                                                                                                                                                                   

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403434/can%27t-install-ros2-humble-on-raspi-with-ubuntu-server-22.04/) by [gm88](https://answers.ros.org/users/35755/gm88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like some update solved the problem. Repeating the above steps with the current kernel and package versions works fine. Current kernel version:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-1013-raspi #15-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT ...
```

---

Originally posted by [gm88](https://answers.ros.org/users/35755/gm88/) with karma: 13 on 2022-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1